# Onmouseout in <td> triggers when child elements inside it are accessed

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

```
<td align="left" valign="top" onmouseout="btnMenuCollapseClicked()">
                          <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" ScrollBars="Auto">

                 <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView2" runat="server" Width="169px" OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged">
                     <Nodes>
                         <asp:TreeNode Text="Main1" Value="Main1">
                             <asp:TreeNode Text="B" Value="B"></asp:TreeNode>
                             <asp:TreeNode Text="C" Value="C"></asp:TreeNode>
                             <asp:TreeNode Text="D" Value="D"></asp:TreeNode>
                         </asp:TreeNode>
                         <asp:TreeNode Text="Main2" Value="Main2">
                             <asp:TreeNode Text="A" Value="A"></asp:TreeNode>
                             <asp:TreeNode Text="B" Value="B"></asp:TreeNode>
                         </asp:TreeNode>
                     </Nodes>
                 </asp:TreeView>

             </asp:Panel>

                 </td>
```

In the above td i have mentioned a onmouseout event But  When i mouse over the treeview present inside the td , the onmouseout event of the td gets triggered . How to avoid this . ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how onmouseout works.

You want to use [onmouseleave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave)

Comment: I dont see onmouseleave event for <td> .

Comment: I have completed using Javascript . the mouseleave is in jquery . Will i be able to achieve this functionality ? If so how can i ?

Comment: $("#TreeView2").mouseout( function btnMenuCollapseClicked() { var treeid = document.getElementById("divMenu"); treeid.style.display = 'none'; var tdMenu = document.getElementById("tdMenu"); tdMenu.style.display = ''; document.getElementById("<%= Page.Master.FindControl("TreeView1").ClientID %>").value = "false"; } );                I made this change , Still the same issue happened .